# Tensorflow Out Of Range while saving weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am getting `OutOfRangeError` when I am trying to save weights and don't necessarily know why. The model seems to be of the size **674.82 MB** and I have **1 TB** hard-disk size on my instance. So, I can't figure why I am getting this error. Below is my model and code to save weights. Let me know if you need anything else to debug the error. The model saves weights if I reduce the hidden layer size from 512 to 128. Does anyone what could be causing this error?

**Model Architecture:**

```
Model: "trxster_prob_512H"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 en_input_layer (InputLayer  [(None, 12)]                 0         []                            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 en_pos_embed_layer (Positi  (None, 12, 512)              159744    ['en_input_layer[0][0]']      
 onalEncodingLayer)                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer1 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_pos_embed_layer[0][0]',  
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_pos_embed_layer[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer1 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer2 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_drop_layer1[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_drop_layer1[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer2 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer3 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_drop_layer2[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_drop_layer2[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer3 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer3[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer4 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_drop_layer3[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_drop_layer3[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer4 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer4[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer5 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_drop_layer4[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_drop_layer4[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer5 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer5[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_input_layer (InputLayer  [(None, 4)]                  0         []                            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 en_sub_layer6 (EncoderSubL  (None, 12, 512)              1050316   ['en_drop_layer5[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    8          'en_drop_layer5[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_pos_embed_layer (Positi  (None, 4, 512)               159744    ['de_input_layer[0][0]']      
 onalEncodingLayer)                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 en_drop_layer6 (Dropout)    (None, 12, 512)              0         ['en_sub_layer6[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer1 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_pos_embed_layer[0][0]',  
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer1 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer2 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_drop_layer1[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer2 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer3 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_drop_layer2[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer3 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer3[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer4 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_drop_layer3[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer4 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer4[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer5 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_drop_layer4[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer5 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer5[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_sub_layer6 (DecoderSubl  (None, 4, 512)               1890560   ['de_drop_layer5[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                    0          'en_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 de_drop_layer6 (Dropout)    (None, 4, 512)               0         ['de_sub_layer6[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 de_output_layer (TimeDistr  (None, 4, 250)               128250    ['de_drop_layer6[0][0]']      
 ibuted)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 176900346 (674.82 MB)
Trainable params: 176900346 (674.82 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

**Training and saving weights:**

```
EPOCHS = 1
stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

trxster.fit(train_ds.take(2),
              epochs=EPOCHS,
              validation_data=val_ds.take(1),
              callbacks=[stop_early])

trxster.save_weights('./saved_models/weights/trxster_sm_prob/trxster_wts')
```

**Error Trace:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last) File <command-1080604003390190>, line 2
      1 # trxster.save('./saved_models/trxster_transformer_model.h5')
----> 2 trxster.save_weights('./saved_models/weights/trxster_sm_prob/trxster_wts')

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:60, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53   # Convert any objects of type core_types.Tensor to Tensor.
     54   inputs = [
     55       tensor_conversion_registry.convert(t)
     56       if isinstance(t, core_types.Tensor)
     57       else t
     58       for t in inputs
     59   ]
---> 60   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     61                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     62 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     63   if name is not None:

OutOfRangeError: {{function_node
__wrapped__SaveV2_dtypes_771_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} saved_models/weights/trxster_sm_prob/trxster_wts_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate10989366996057447488; File too large [Op:SaveV2]
```

Comment: what is your tf version? And can u try saving with .h5 format?

Comment: it is 2.14.0. Saving it in .h5 gives me this error: `RuntimeError: Can't decrement id ref count (unable to extend file properly, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument')`

Comment: have you tried `trxster.save_weights('my_model.h5')`? otherwise, if possible please share the model definition (code).